# What is the transformation group for fermions under general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, fermions

In General Relativity the objects transform under the general linear group GL(3,1).

Does this include fermions? If you rotate an object around $360^{\circ}$ the fermions inside the object will not be the same until you rotate it round another $360^{\circ}$.

So what is the generalisation of GL(3,1) to fermions? Is it GL(3,1,C)? or something else? I presume it must have SU(2)xSU(2) as a subgroup.

Comment: You have to actually define the objects you want to act upon and the type of symmetry you're looking at. It is in general not true that *"...In General Relativity the objects transform under the general linear group..."* because for example single coordinates transform under diffeomorphisms. Also, "fermions" is very vague: what object do you have in mind?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225413/2451 and links therein.