# Is Einstein's GR field equations covariant under local diffeomorphisms?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, geometry

Given that a local diffeomorphism is not necessarily a [global] diffeomorphism, I wonder if Einstein's GR in covariant under local diffeomorphisms of a Lorenzian manifold?

If so, why do we interpret general covariance as [global] diffeomorphism covariance and not local diffeomorphism covariance?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225413/2451