# What are the local Lorentz transformations in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, gauge-invariance

What is the exact form of local Lorentz transformations (from the point of view of the metric) in a curved spacetime background like in general relativity?  It should deviate substantially from ordinary Lorentz transformations in Minkowski space.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190243/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thank you.i was thinking if one can do this directly?suppose for static observer we got a form of metric and from that we directly go to another inertial frame and then get lorentz transform directly.can this be done?

Comment: The metric is INVARIANT under local Lorentz transformations! In addition to local vs. global, there is a fine distinction (often not pointed out in text books) between the local Lorentz transformations in general relativity and global Lorentz transformations in special relativity. See details here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502982/the-role-of-lorentz-tranformations/503119#503119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is such a thing in **GR**. These are the rotations of *tetrads*.

At each point of a space define an orthonormal basis:
$$
(\vec e_{(a)}, \vec e_{(b)}) = \eta_{ab}
$$
Where $a, b$ - denote the indices, corresponding to the local frame, in constract to the Greek spacetime indices $\mu, \nu$.
The coordinate basis is related to the local basis, by some invertible $4 \times 4$ matrix :
$$
\vec e_{\mu} = e_{\mu}^{a} \vec e_a 
$$
The metric in the coordinate space is expressed therefore, as:
$$
g_{\mu \nu}= e_{\mu}^{a} e_{\nu}^{b} \eta_{ab}
$$
*Local Lorentz transformations* can be made at any point:
$$
\vec e_a  = \Lambda_a^{b} (x) \vec e_b
$$
Where the matrix of transformation depends on the point $x$.

For a good reference I recommend - https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2037.

Comment: Thank you.of course this can be done.i was thinking if one can do this directly?suppose for static observer we got a form of metric and from that we directly go to another inertial frame and then get lorentz transform directly.can this be done?

Comment: "from the point of view of the metric": The metric is INVARIANT under local Lorentz transformations! If you use eq(27) from the  link (https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2037) provided in the answer, you can clearly see that  $g_{\mu \nu}= e_{\mu}^{a} e_{\nu}^{b}\eta_{ab}$ is invariant.